# Apparent memory leak when initiating Keras ImageDataGenerator few times

Tags: python, keras, imagedatagenerator

My first question, so please bare with me...

I have a big dataset that does not fit in the memory. I also have to manipulate the data before usage and I have 6 input channels.
I initiate the image data generator few times in the program and the memory consumption grows times and again.

I try to load part of the data -> train the model -> reload some new data -> train -> load ->... using the code below, the data consumption grows in each iteration till the memory is finished. Any idea how can I refresh the training data?

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
seed=100

def combine_generator(gen0, gen1):
    while True:
        yield (next(gen0), next(gen1))

def populate_set(elements=1e6):
    data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        rotation_range=7.0,
        width_shift_range=0.04,
        height_shift_range=0.04,
        shear_range=0.025,
        zoom_range=0.03,
        fill_mode='constant',
        cval=0,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        vertical_flip=False)
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    images = np.zeros((elements, 224, 224, 6), dtype=np.uint8)
    labels = np.zeros((elements, 224, 224, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow(images, batch_size=16, seed=seed)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(labels, batch_size=16, seed=seed)
    generator = combine_generator(image_generator, mask_generator)
    return images, labels, generator


max_elem = 4000
max_valid = 2000
trainImgs, trainlabels, train_generator = populate_set(elements=max_elem)
testImgs, testlabels, test_generator = populate_set(elements=max_valid)
for train1 in range(0,1000):
    # hist = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=test_generator,
    # validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_val,
    #                      steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs_together)
    # replace the train data
    trainImgs, trainlabels, train_generator = populate_set( elements=max_elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a shame. I had to do the ugliest workaround. I used multiprocessing and did the work on a child process that was killed in each iteration. :(

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
seed=100

def combine_generator(gen0, gen1):
    while True:
        yield (next(gen0), next(gen1))

def populate_set(elements=1e6):
    data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        rotation_range=7.0,
        width_shift_range=0.04,
        height_shift_range=0.04,
        shear_range=0.025,
        zoom_range=0.03,
        fill_mode='constant',
        cval=0,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        vertical_flip=False)
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    images = np.zeros((elements, 224, 224, 6), dtype=np.uint8)
    labels = np.zeros((elements, 224, 224, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow(images, batch_size=16, seed=seed)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(labels, batch_size=16, seed=seed)
    generator = combine_generator(image_generator, mask_generator)
    return images, labels, generator




max_elem = 15000
max_valid = 2000


def populate_set_wrapper(**kwargs):
    kwarg_elements = kwargs.get('elements', False)
    populate_set(elements=kwarg_elements)
    # do the training here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for train1 in range(0,1000):
        # hist = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_val,
        #                      steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epochs_together)
        # replace the train data
        # trainImgs, trainlabels, train_generator = populate_set( elements=max_elem)
        p = Process(target=populate_set_wrapper, kwargs={"elements":max_elem,} )
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print("iter:" + str(train1))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).